# Can a destructuring assign create a public and private val at the same time

Tags: scala

Is there a syntax that would allow me to clean up a pattern like the below as a one-liner?

```scala
private val (_a, b) = (1, 2)
val a = _a
```

I'm imagining something like

```scala
val (a, private b) = (1, 2)
```

The goal is that one half of the destructuring assign becomes a public val, and the other becomes private.

FWIW I'm using Scala 2, but if this is possible with Scala 3 I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such possibility but you could do it in the following way for more expressiveness and handle various tuples maybe:

```scala
// Actual value computed somehow
private val x = (1, 2, 3)

// Keeping the 1st item private
private val (a, _, _) = x
// Making the 2nd and 3rd public
val (_, b, c) = x
```

Or, probably better for the long term, don't use tuples but actual class/case class with private/public attributes?